# Docker Compose Multiple SSL Virtual Hosts

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm using Let's Encrypt companion on docker-compose v3. I have multiple hosts with SSL. On my Nginx container I expose:

```
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.example.com,service.example.com
  - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=api.example.com,service.example.com
  - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=tech@example.com
```

This setting is working fine except for the fact that if I read SSL certificate details on *service.example.com* I get as name *api.example.com*.
Is this the expected behaviour or can I fix it somehow? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be the expected behaviour for SAN (Subject Alternative Name) certificate. [Here](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/issues/343) github discussion.